# Trying to understand between new Promise and Async/await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a very basic question:

This code

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

gives this output, which is correct:

```
> "calling"
> "resolved"
```

This one however:

```
async function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return 'resolved';
    }, 2000);
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

It gives instead:

```
> "calling"
> undefined
```

From javascript.info:

> The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function
> always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved
> promise automatically. So, async ensures that the function returns a
> promise, and wraps non-promises in it

So there's something I am misunderstanding, isn't the resolveAfter2Seconds returning a promise in both scenarios (the resolveAfter2Seconds  in the 2nd scenario has async)? If so why the output in the 2nd scenario?

Comment: `resolveAfter2Seconds()` returns a Promise that will resolve to `undefined` (because the function itself doesn't return anything)

Comment: Your second resolveAfter2Seconds returns a promise of undefined that resolves immediately. The return in the setTimeout callback is **not** the same as returning from the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a pretty basic beginner mistake you use `return` in an callback and expect to recevive something from the parent function

This here:

```
async function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return 'resolved';
    }, 2000);
}
```

Can be written to this here:

```
async function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      return 'resolved';
    }, 2000);
}
```

And as you can see there is a second function and you return `resolved` to your callback function. There is actually no way to return this value like you want to, you will need to use Promises like in your first example

Since `resolveAfter2Seconds` doesnt return anything it will return by default `undefined`

No `return` = returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

> In the second case, you are not returning anything from the
> `resolveAfter2Seconds` function, the return in the code is for the
> callback of the `setTimeout`, which will not be returned by the
> `resolveAfter2Seconds` function. Hence the `undefined`.

Comment: thank you all, in this case how can I make an async function to behave like a function wrapped with new Promise, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are returning a promise, the main differences between the two are when each promise resolves and what each promise resolves to. In your second function `resolveAfter2Seconds`, you're only returning inside of the setTimeout function, and  as a result, you  return back to the caller of the setTimeout callback function, not your `resolveAfter2Seconds`. Rather, your `resolveAfter2Seconds` doesn't return anything, and so it will implicitly return `undefined` which gets wrapped within a promise. It is more or less the same as writing:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return 'resolved';
    }, 2000);
      
    return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
```

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return 'resolved';
  }, 2000);

  return Promise.resolve(undefined); // returns  a promise which resolves with the value of `undefined`
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

The above returns a Promise which resolves immediately with the value of `undefined`. As a  result,  you either need to explicitly wrap your setTimeout in a promise and `resolve()` (like  your first `resolveAfter2Seconds`), or use something like a helper sleep method:

```js
const sleep = n => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, n));
async function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  await sleep(2000);
  return "resolved";
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

Comment: This sleep method is genius, kinda reminds me of Powershell's Start-Sleep thing; but I don't think it's a common thing in the real world of JS. Is there any practical use for it?

With your sleep example, I can understand now why in Angular for example, when I call a service async function which does a http request then it works as expected, the http request return a promise too.

Comment: @cupcake I've personally never used a `sleep` helper function before, as callbacks do the trick (such as your first example). The example is more to help illustrate the idea of how one could return a promise which resolves to a particular value without explicitly needing to use `resolve()` and a Promise constructor. Some people might find it more readable though if you need to write this type of code multiple times throughout your code.